# Google Analytics Event Tracking onClick issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, onclick

I am setting up event tracking for several buttons on a landing page, I've added onClick code to each, however it doesn't appear clicks are sending any data to Google Analytics. I am getting an error in console when I inspect in Chrome "Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick". I'm trying to track clicks on 3 separate buttons.

My tracking code is:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-3133XXXX-X');
</script>

The code I am using for each button is:

<div class="get-ticket-btn"> <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($landing_page->ID, "landing_tickets_url", true);?>" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Button Click', 'Get Ticket click', 'Get Tickets Now');" class="btn">Get Tickets Now !</a> </div>

<button type="submit" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Button Click', 'Get Coupon click', 'Get My Coupon');" class="btn btn-default">GET MY COUPON</button>

<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($landing_page->ID, "landing_tickets_url", true);?>" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Button Click', 'Get Ticket click', 'Get Tickets Now');" class="btn">Get Tickets Now !</a> </div>
```

Comment: Are you importing the Google Analytics script somewhere on the page before trying to use it?

Comment: @dangowans Yes the GA Tracking script is in the header of the page.

Comment: @kgrg Thanks that led me to finding the correct solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by following the recommendations here https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/gtag-js-event-tracking-for-mailto-and-tellephone-link-not/td-p/1259427

The issue was I was using "ga" instead of "gtag", also with the use of "gtag" there is no need to use 'send'.